# CodeIgniter Preventing Uploads?

Tags: iphone, xcode, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter for an iPhone app I have. The app allows for users to share images to specific individuals. It works great great, but it seems that after a certain amount of pictures to sent to an individual, posts fail to upload. I was wondering if there is something within CodeIgniter that is causing this issue and how to fix it.

here is part of our config file:

```
$config['proxy_ips'] = '';

$config['upload_group_path'] = "./upload/group";
$config['upload_user_path'] = "./upload/users";
$config['upload_photo_path'] = "./upload/photo";
$config['upload_video_path'] = "./upload/video";
$config['upload_weblink_path'] = "./upload/weblink";
$config['upload_drawing_path'] = "./upload/drawing";
$config['upload_text_path'] = "./upload/text";

$config['upload_movietype'] = 'mp4|flv|3gp|wmv';
$config['upload_moviesize'] = 100 * 1024; // 100M

$config['upload_alltype']   = '*';
$config['upload_allsize']   = 100 * 1024; // 100M

$config['upload_imgtype']   = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|jpeg|jpe';
$config['upload_imgsize']   = 5 * 1024; // 5M
$config['upload_thumb_mw']  = '80';
$config['upload_thumb_mh']  = '60';

$config['upload_kmltype']   = 'kml';
$config['upload_kmlsize']   = 10 * 1024; // 10M

$config['main_category'] = array(
'user'  =>  'Users',
'photo' =>  'Photos',
);

$config['difficulty'] = array(
'Easy'      =>  'Easy',
'Moderate'  =>  'Moderate',
'Difficult' =>  'Difficult',
);

$config['max_count_per_page'] = 5;

$config['thumb_name'] = "_thumb";
$config['photo_name'] = "_photo";
```

And part of our api file (that draws the error 'fail to upload' in xcode's output):

```
    $tbl_name = "posts";
    $new_idx = $this->api_m->get_next_insert_idx($tbl_name);
    if (isset($_FILES['datafile']) && $_FILES['datafile']['name'] != '') {
        $conf = array();
        $conf['upload_path']    = $this->api_m->get_upload_path($postType, $ownerID."_".$format);
        $conf['allowed_types']  = $this->config->item('upload_alltype');
        $conf['max_size']       = $this->config->item('upload_allsize');
        $conf['overwrite']      = FALSE;
        $conf['remove_spaces']  = TRUE;

        if (!file_exists($conf['upload_path'])) {
            mkdir($conf['upload_path']);
        }

        $this->upload->initialize($conf);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('datafile')) {

            $fileinfo = $this->upload->data();
            if ($fileinfo['file_size'] > 0) {
                $postURL = base_url().substr($conf['upload_path'], 2)."/".$fileinfo['file_name'];
                if ($postType == "video") {
                    $referenceData = base_url().substr($conf['upload_path'], 2)."/".$fileinfo['file_name'];
                    if (isset($_FILES['thumbfile']) && $_FILES['thumbfile']['name'] != '') {
                        $conf = array();
                        $conf['upload_path']    = $this->api_m->get_upload_path($postType, $ownerID."_".$format);
                        $conf['allowed_types']  = $this->config->item('upload_alltype');
                        $conf['max_size']       = $this->config->item('upload_allsize');
                        $conf['overwrite']      = FALSE;
                        $conf['remove_spaces']  = TRUE;

                        if (!file_exists($conf['upload_path'])) {
                            mkdir($conf['upload_path']);
                        }

                        $this->upload->initialize($conf);
                        if ($this->upload->do_upload('thumbfile')) {
                            $fileinfo = $this->upload->data();
                            $baseName = $this->api_m->_img_resize($postType, $fileinfo, $fileinfo['raw_name'], $new_idx);
                            $postURL = base_url().substr($conf['upload_path'], 2)."/".$baseName;
                            $baseName = $this->api_m->_img_thumb($postType, $fileinfo, $fileinfo['raw_name'], $new_idx);
                            $thumbURL = base_url().substr($conf['upload_path'], 2)."/".$baseName;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $baseName = $this->api_m->_img_thumb($postType, $fileinfo, $fileinfo['raw_name'], $new_idx);
                    $thumbURL = base_url().substr($conf['upload_path'], 2)."/".$baseName;
                }
                $uploadMsg = "success";
            }
        } else {
            $uploadMsg = "fail to upload";
        }
    } else {
        $uploadMsg = "select the post data";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit in Codeigniter for how many files you can upload, however are you uploading more than one file at a time so that you might reach the limit for how big files you may upload? Either in CI config or the server config.

EDIT!
Try using $this->upload->display_errors() to see what's is going wrong according to CI. My guess now is that the filename allready exists, but I'm curios to see what you get.

2nd EDIT!
In your configuration or before you load your upload class you can set the setting: max_filename_increment. When overwrite is set to FALSE, use this to set the maximum filename increment for CodeIgniter to append to the filename.

```
$conf['max_filename_increment'] = // What ever number you think is reasonable
```

Fix this and you should be good to go again :)

3rd EDIT!
I'm sorry that setting isn't available yet. So either you have to add your own upload class in your applications folder there are guides for how to add custom libraries to codeigniter else you will have to edit the Upload class in system. Note that it is not recommended to update anything in the system folder since it would be overwritten if you would update you version of CI later.

But I will of course let you know how to edit the class if you want to;

In the folder libraries in CI system you find the file Upload.php. In the latest version you find the function set_filename() on row 390. Scroll down to row 406 and you should see

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 100; $i++)
```

This is the loop that takes too few turns for your file names to be incremented. exchange 100 to a new number and try again.

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 1000; $i++)
```

That will loop ten times more than before, but I guess the limit is there for performance so check your response times before and after editing this and when uploading 3-500 files with the same name?

Regards

Comment: I am only uploading one file at a time, and they work every time until an "inbox" (essentially) hits ~150 posts, new posts stop going through. I really doubt it is our server, as we experience this same error on our localhost. I also doubt the error is from xcode because other post types continue to post fine (i.e. only photos stop posting, sending videos still works). I tried adjusting the CI config, but nothing I tried worked. I will update my original post now with some of our code which can hopefully help us (you) troubleshoot. Thanks so much...

Comment: Thanks Tobias, I think it is a file-naming issue. I double checked my upload directories and the uploads are numbered 1.jpg-19.jpg then 110.jpg-199.jpg. Then the system seems to be unable to continue after that (i.e. it cannot create a 200.jpg. Strange. What is the file that I need to adjust to fix this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have edited my answer again. If this solves your problem please mark this answer as the solution. Good luck!

Comment: I added this code to my file and it had no effect. :/ Any other ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: What number did you set? Can you please update your code so that I can see how you did it?

Comment: Ok now I edited my answer again, sorry for the incorrect code earlier, hope you find the rows and code that I'm talking about in my edit.